# How can I send an announcement of a specific role change to a specific channel?

Tags: discord.js

I'd like to notify our main chat channel when a role has changed for someone, a specific role though -- how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question well. You have to use the [guildMemberUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event to check if the roles are still the same if the event gets triggered. Then, you have to run a simple for loop and check which roles have been removed or assigned from the guildMember.

Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('guildMemberupdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const messagechannel = oldMember.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === 'Name of the channel where the announcement should be sent');
    if (!messagechannel) return 'Channel does not exist!';

    if (oldMember.roles.size < newMember.roles.size) {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('ORANGE')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor('Role assigned')
            .addField(` Member:`, `${oldMember.user.tag} (${oldMember.id})`);

        for (const role of newMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) {
            if (!oldMember.roles.has(role)) {
                embed.addField(` Role(s):`, `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}`);
            }
        }
        messagechannel.send({
            embed
        });
    }

    if (oldMember.roles.size > newMember.roles.size) {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('ORANGE')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor('Role removed')
            .addField(` Member`, `${oldMember.user.tag} (${oldMember.id})`);

        for (const role of oldMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) {
            if (!newMember.roles.has(role)) {
                embed.addField(` Role(s):`, `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}`);
            }
        }
        messagechannel.send({
            embed
        });
    }
});
```